# How to set Runtime.PythonDLL for PythonNET for Console & WPF .NET Application (PIP Installation)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, python.net

I am trying to install `PythonNET` on `Python 3.10` and embedding Python into the .NET console app first before subsequently trying it on the WPF app.

However, I am still confused about the installation for `PythonNET`, after downloading the Native code on [GitHub](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) and installing it within the unzipped code folder via `pip install .`. The install does complete successfully, and `Python.RunTime.dll` here `C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pythonnet\runtime\Python.RunTime.dll`.

However, when I try pointing towards it in C# code, it still triggers the `BadPythonDllException` error.

**C# Configuration**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;        // For some implementation using List<> later on
using Python.Runtime;

namespace ConsoleApp_PythonNET_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string EnvPath = @"C: \Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310";
            string pythonPath = @"C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pythonnet";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", EnvPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", pythonPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            PythonEngine.PythonHome = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            PythonEngine.PythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            //Using (Py.GIL()) Method for some Python implementations
        }
    }
}
```

Can I check what I am missing? Am I simply still pointing towards the wrong dir? Additionally, would the embedding process be the same within a WPF application, or would there be any additional step(s) required?

Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Comment: Seems that library doesn't support python 3.10 yet, 3.9 is supported https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/releases

Comment: Hm I have downloaded 3.9.7 and added it into the System Environment Variables PATH and re-installed PythonNET to the 3.9.7 dir instead. However, it still throws the `BadPythonDllException` error.

Comment: For me adding path to python39 to the system environment variable "Path" via Windows control panel worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `README` in the repository:

`Runtime.PythonDLL` ... typical values are `python38.dll` (Windows), `libpython3.8.dylib` (Mac), `libpython3.8.so` (most other *nix).

E.g. you need to set `Runtime.PythonDLL` to path to `python39.dll`.

When embedding into C#, there's no need to install the pip package. The NuGet will be enough.

Comment: Hi @LOST, thanks, essentially it seems like I needed to add `Runtime.PythonDLL = @"env\python37.dll";` path before `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()` and avoid hard-setting the path for `PYTHONPATH` since it might throw `Fatal Python error: initfsencoding` due to incorrect path.