# How do I Configure and Initialize Python.NET in a C# Console App on Linux containerized with Docker?

Tags: python, c#, linux, docker, python.net

I am trying to run a C#/.NET console application that uses the Python.NET library to interpret Python scripts at runtime. I want this app to run on Linux with a Docker container.

The problem I am having is that Python.NET requires you to initialize the `Runtime.PythonDLL` property with the path to the Python library binary.

The answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670715/how-to-set-runtime-pythondll-for-pythonnet-for-console-wpf-net-application-p) makes me suspect I am looking for a file named e.g. `libpython3.12.so`.

I have created a dockerfile (see below) that installs the `python:3` image to a virtual environment and copies the result into my final environment. But I do not see any file named like `libpython3.12.so`. If I try to provide the `/app/python/bin/python` executable (which *does* exist), Python.NET throws an exception (see below) that the file does not exist.

I can't find an explicit guide to how this should be done, does one exist?

How should I configure my dockerfile, and what is the path to the `libpython*.so` file that I should assign to `Runtime.PythonDLL`?

---

The .dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Farpoint.Service/Farpoint.Service.csproj", "Farpoint.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Farpoint.Service/Farpoint.Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Farpoint.Service"
RUN dotnet build "Farpoint.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# BEGIN Prepare python env
FROM python:3 as python
RUN python -m venv /venv
COPY --from=build /app/build/python/requirements.txt .
RUN /venv/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# END Prepare python env

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Farpoint.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# BEGIN Copy python env
COPY --from=python /venv /app/python
# END Copy python env

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Farpoint.Service.dll"]
```

---

The exception:

> DllNotFoundException: Could not load /app/python/bin/python with flags RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL: /app/python/bin/python: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory